# Connectiong to XAMPP FTP from another pc

Tags: ftp, filezilla, xampp

So I have a website, and I'm tring to setup FTP. When I on the virtual windows machine start FileZilla in XAMPP, and then try to connect to it, it works fine, and I can also upload files to the FTP folder:

[image]
[image]

Now I'm trying to see if it's possible to connect to the FTP from my own PC (not through VM), and I'm on the same network.
But now I get an error
[image]

I thought it might have something to do with the firewall, but to me it looks fine (VM machine where XAMPP runs)
[image]

Do anyone know what I'm missing before it's possible to connect to the FTP, on my own pc?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't mention the VM software you are using, but virtual machines are often isolated from the host machine by default. In my experience, the most common ways to generally access a VM are via:

- A bridged connection, where the VM uses the host's network connection and appears as a separate computer with its own IP on the network.
- A NAT connection, where connections to the VM use the host's IP address and the VM software can be set up effectively like a router, which uses "port forwarding" to pass connection requests to the correct VM.

In the first case, you would need to specify the IP of the VM in your FTP command. In the second case, you would need to take steps to ensure the VM software itself had the correct "port forwarding" settings enabled and use the host's IP address to make the connection. Of course, you would still need the proper firewall settings on the host and the guest to allow FTP connections, as well as the proper settings in FileZilla Server (or what have you) to allow remote connections as well.

Comment: Its a VM running windows 10, and i use filezilla server yes